# Percona XtraDB Cluster - Node Won't Join

Tags: rsync, mysql-replication, percona-xtradb-cluster

I am trying to add a node to a new cluster but am met with the following log entries:

```
120915 16:47:32 [Warning] WSREP: error executing 'SET GLOBAL innodb_disallow_writes=1': 1193 (Unknown system variable 'innodb_disallow_writes'). Was mysqld built with --with-innodb-disallow-writes ?
120915 16:47:32 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to disallow InnoDB writes
    rsync: open "mysql/dummy.bak" (in rsync_sst) failed: Permission denied (13)
    rsync: open "test/dummy.bak" (in rsync_sst) failed: Permission denied (13)
    rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1070) [sender=3.0.9]
    rsync returned code 23:
120915 16:47:45 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to read from: wsrep_sst_rsync 'donor' '10.194.110.201:4444/rsync_sst' 'wsrep_sst:wspass' '/usr/local/mysql-5.5/data/' '/etc/my.cnf' 'b334d89c-ff6c-11e1-0800-ba5125ffffff' '2' '0'
120915 16:47:45 [Warning] WSREP: error executing 'SET GLOBAL innodb_disallow_writes=0': 1193 (Unknown system variable 'innodb_disallow_writes'). Was mysqld built with --with-innodb-disallow-writes ?
120915 16:47:45 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to disallow InnoDB writes
120915 16:47:45 [Note] WSREP: Provider resumed.
120915 16:47:45 [ERROR] WSREP: Process completed with error: wsrep_sst_rsync 'donor' '10.1.1.2:4444/rsync_sst' 'wsrep_sst:wspass' '/usr/local/mysql-5.5/data/' '/etc/my.cnf' 'b334d89c-ff6c-11e1-0800-ba5125ffffff' '2' '0': 255 (Unknown error 255)
120915 16:47:45 [Warning] WSREP: 0 (master): State transfer to 1 (slave1) failed: -1 (Operation not permitted)
```

My node1 (`gcomm://`) starts and shows 1 node in cluster. I updated node2 to point to node1, restart, and the following appears consistently, causing MySQL to crash.

It looks like part of the issue may be related to `rsync` failing allong with `Unknown error 255`.

My node1 is `10.1.1.1` and listening on `3306` and `4567` (by default).

**Update**: I changed SST type to `mysqldump` and it started working. But since then, performance has been very poor:

```
mysql> show databases;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
ERROR:
Can't connect to the server

mysql> show databases;
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    1
Current database: *** NONE ***

ERROR 1317 (70100): Query execution was interrupted
mysql> show databases;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    7
Current database: *** NONE ***

+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| Text               |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Also, this is located in `.err`

```
19:41:41 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
Please help us make Percona Server better by reporting any
bugs at http://bugs.percona.com/

key_buffer_size=33554432
read_buffer_size=2097152
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=100
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 1058026 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.


120919 15:42:33 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql-5.5/data
120919 15:42:33 [Note] Flashcache bypass: disabled
120919 15:42:33 [Note] Flashcache setup error is : ioctl failed

120919 15:42:33 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120919 15:42:33 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120919 15:42:33 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
120919 15:42:33 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
120919 15:42:33 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.0G
120919 15:42:34 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120919 15:42:34 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
120919 15:42:34  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
120919 15:42:34  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140700858599232 in file fsp0fsp.c line 2938
InnoDB: Failing assertion: space != 0
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.


Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/local/mysql-5.5/bin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x29)[0x786eb9]
/usr/local/mysql-5.5/bin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x367)[0x678597]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfcb0)[0x7f97d479ecb0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7f97d3e0e445]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x17b)[0x7f97d3e11bab]
/usr/local/mysql-5.5/bin/mysqld[0x8b5f02]
/usr/local/mysql-5.5/bin/mysqld[0x8b63b5]
/usr/local/mysql-5.5/bin/mysqld[0x84db6f]
/usr/local/mysql-5.5/bin/mysqld[0x884f39]
/usr/local/mysql-5.5/bin/mysqld[0x8857bf]
/usr/local/mysql-5.5/bin/mysqld[0x82a9d5]
/usr/local/mysql-5.5/bin/mysqld[0x7ed3b9]
/usr/local/mysql-5.5/bin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x41)[0x67a721]
/usr/local/mysql-5.5/bin/mysqld[0x593c35]
/usr/local/mysql-5.5/bin/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0x829)[0x597b69]
/usr/local/mysql-5.5/bin/mysqld[0x51a8d7]
/usr/local/mysql-5.5/bin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x953)[0x51f1a3]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7f97d3df976d]
/usr/local/mysql-5.5/bin/mysqld[0x515e45]
You may download the Percona Server operations manual by visiting
http://www.percona.com/software/percona-server/. You may find information
in the manual which will help you identify the cause of the crash.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `120915 16:47:32 [Warning] WSREP: error executing 'SET GLOBAL
>   innodb_disallow_writes=1': 1193 (Unknown system variable
>   'innodb_disallow_writes'). Was mysqld built with
>   --with-innodb-disallow-writes ?`
>
> `120915 16:47:32 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to disallow InnoDB writes`

Although the [`mysqlbug`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbug.html) is obsolete in 5.5, it still can be used to get the compile options. Make sure that you see `-DWITH_INNODB_DISALLOW_WRITES` in the `Compilation info (used):` line:

`Compilation info (used): CC='/usr/bin/gcc44'  CFLAGS='-fPIC -Wall -O3 -g -static-libgcc -fno-omit-frame-pointer -DPERCONA_INNODB_VERSION=rel28.1    -DWITH_WSREP -DWSREP_PROC_INFO -DMYSQL_MAX_VARIABLE_VALUE_LEN=2048 -DWITH_INNODB_DISALLOW_WRITES...`

> ```
> rsync: open "mysql/dummy.bak" (in rsync_sst) failed: Permission denied (13)
> rsync: open "test/dummy.bak" (in rsync_sst) failed: Permission denied (13)
> ```

What are permissions of these files?

> **Update**: I changed SST type to `mysqldump` and it started working.

Quite strange. Don't you get `Unknown system variable 'innodb_disallow_writes'`?

> Also, this is located in `.err`
>
> ```
> 19:41:41 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
> This could be because you hit a bug...
> ```

Could you please post some lines above this? Have you tried to use `xtrabackup` method?

Comment: Thanks @quanta. I updated the above. So. Someone the dummy.bak files were owned by root, which they should be owned by mysql. Anyway.. I deleted ibdata[01] and ib_logfile* and everything was fine. Thanks for the help..